# Power method for solving a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, analytic-geometry

Given a set of $n$ points on which a triangulation is performed, it is possible to construct coefficients $\lambda_{ij}>0$ such that each point $x_i$ is a convex combination of the points connected to it. Suppose $N(i)$ is a set of points adjacent to $x_i$ in a triangulation; then, for each $x_i$,

$$\sum_{j\in N(i)} \lambda_{ij}x_j = x_i $$

and

$$\sum_{j\in N(i)} \lambda_j = 1.$$

In matrix form,

$$\Lambda x=x$$

where $\Lambda$ is a square, $n\times n$, row stochastic matrix (non-negative entries, and no self-loops).

Now suppose matrix $\Lambda$ is given. Can one reach configuration $x$ by the Power Method, i.e., repeatedly multiplying $\Lambda$ by a vector? I am asking because the above matrix form reminds me of the eigenvalue/eigenvector definition. If not, what would be a good approach to compute such a configuration? Is the solution unique?

One more interesting question: can the coefficients $\lambda_{ij}$ be constructed in such a way that $\lambda_{ij} = \lambda_{ji}$, i.e., the matrix $\Lambda$ is symmetric, that is to say doubly stochastic? This way of constructing coefficients means that the Power Method should converge to $x$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the context. But if the norm of the matrix $\boldsymbol \varLambda - \boldsymbol I$ is less than some fixed number $q < 1$ then the method would converge.

Comment: @ xbh The diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ are zeroes, meaning that each row of $\Lambda - I$ would sum to zero. Could you please provide more details on the "norm" claim?

Comment: The Power Method is an eigenvalue algorithm that only finds the largest eigenvalue and eigenvector. It isn't used for solving systems of equations. There are variants used for different types of matrices. However, your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @ Geronimo If it is known that the solution to the system is the dominant eigenvector of the involved matrix, why can't it be used?